# How to use a function in Google Sheets to Populate a Table

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to automatically populate a table (set of cells) in Google Sheets with tennis player names. If you look at the attached image, I want to be able to enter a number in cell A25, do a VLOOKUP from another sheet to pull the player name, then, if the player is found, add them to the end of the list (until max 16 players).

Currently I use this function in each cell and populate manually on a line-by-line basis

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,Players!$A$2:Players!$B$1012,2).
```

What I would really like to do is enter a player ID in A25 then have it do the VLOOKUP (like the code) and add the result to the list as mentioned before.

I'm not sure if I should be using an array or whatever to do this? I'm obviously a novice with GS.

Anyone every done anything like this before?

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This does the same as I had before though. It populates the cell to the left with the players name. I was hoping to enter the ID in A25 & then it would get the name and the ID and move them up to the next available line in the list. So like Player 1 would go to line A& B9, Player two would move to A & B10 etc.

Is that possible?

Thanks again for responding.

Mark

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like your answer doesn’t exactly answer your question, but is a response to something else. For responses, use comments.

Answer (score -1):

delete all in range B9:B25 and use this in B9:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A9:A25, Players!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```